# Rails 4 on Heroku extremely slow with loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, newrelic

I've got Heroku deployment with my Rails 4 app and it's proving to be extremely slow. I'm not sure if my location has a factor as I'm based in Australia

I've got NewRelic addon and below is the problem that I'm seeing.

```
Category     Segment                 % Time  Avg calls   Avg Time (ms) 
View         layouts/users Template  98.4    1.0         16,800
```

Based on this breakdown, I see that layout users is the problem for the performance (which is nearly 16.8 seconds!).

Is there a good way to profile this to find out exactly what functions are causing this problem and what are the best way to fix those?

Also another important thing to note is that when I go to `map` report it shows `End User` of 19.5 seconds which takes up a lot of time.

Comment: Is this with only one Dyno running?  Is the load time slow after more than one request is made within the same minute or so?

Comment: @Ecnalyr I have three dynos but I heard Dynos are more for scalability. It runs much faster when I run the app locally...

Comment: I mentioned multiple dynos because, as Guarish Sharma pointed out, if you use one dyno the app 'goes to sleep' -- having more than 1 dyno active prevents this 'sleep' feature.  The app will always be awake, so you won't have the slow initial load time.

Comment: @Ecnalyr how do I make it so app is always awake? I have three dynos

Comment: If they are turned on, they should be awake.  Have you tried typing this in your console: heroku ps:scale web=3 ?  You might actually only have 1 dyno running.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails3#dyno-sleeping-and-scaling  . . .  Referencing the article, you may also have 1 web dyno and 2 worker dynos, you need at least 2 web dynos.

Comment: @Ecnalyr I just tried doing that it is now scaled but still experiencing slowness somehow

Comment: Are you only slow on the first load, or on all loads (if the app was 'asleep' it would only be slow on the first request).  If it is slow on subsequent requests then it is not a 'sleeping' issue.

Comment: @Ecnalyr it's only on first load...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45723/discussion-between-ecnalyr-and-passionate-developer)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as you do. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

When an app on Heroku has only one web dyno and that dyno doesn't receive any traffic in 1 hour, the dyno goes to sleep.

When someone accesses the app, the dyno manager will automatically wake up the web dyno to run the web process type. This causing delay for this first request.

Are you noticing similar behaviour?

Comment: OK thanks. How can we prevent this so that it runs fast from first time

Comment: Apps that have more than 1 web dyno running never sleep.Incase, you don't want to pay for extra dyno then you can ping your site every hr, to keep it awake using service like http://www.pingdom.com/, http://monitive.com/ etc.